# Holiday Gift Exchange

Tags: code-golf

Another problem from our internal golfing...this one around the holidays last year.

### PROBLEM

Andy, Barb, Carl, Didi, Earl, and Fran are buying gifts for each other. Draw names for a gift exchange.

1. Each person buys one gift and receives one gift.
2. Nobody buys their own gift.
3. Running the solution multiple times should produce different results (giver-receiver pair should not be predictable or identical from run to run).

### INPUT

None.

### OUTPUT

Formatted as in this example:

> Andy buys for Barb
>   Barb buys for Carl
>   Carl buys for Didi
>   Didi buys for Earl
>   Earl buys for Fran
>   Fran buys for Andy

Comment: Should the output be sorted by name?

Comment: @Eelvex Nope, not necessary.

Comment: This was duplicated by a question today and the keyword I searched for didn't turn it up, so for future searches: derangement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### J, 57

```
(,.' buys for ',"1|.)(?~6){6 4$'AndyBarbCarlDidiEarlFran'
```

eg

```
   (,.' buys for ',"1|.)(?~6){6 4$'AndyBarbCarlDidiEarlFran'
Carl buys for Earl
Andy buys for Barb
Fran buys for Didi
Didi buys for Fran
Barb buys for Andy
Earl buys for Carl
```

Comment: I don't know [J], but would this work if the names had with different lengths?

Comment: No. The code exploits the fact that all names are 4 characters long. It'll work for different lengths with very few changes.

Comment: This also exploits that there is an even number of people. Note that if X gives to Y, Y will always give to X too.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt -R, 41 bytes

```
`AÌ)B¼C¤E¤FÎÂDi¹`qe ö¬ê1 ò mq` ¿ys f
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Oliver!

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEHMKUKHvEOHpEWHpEbOwkRpuWBxZSD2rOoxIPIgbXFgIL95cyBmjiA=&input=LVI=)

This is the approach I took at a high level:

- uncompress a string containing participants names
- split string into an array
- shuffle it
- assign each person to the person with the next highest index
- the last person in the array gets assigned to the first

I have a little history with this problem as I created a "secret santa" program for my work years ago. We ended up asking a few job applicants to work through it as well :)

Comment: @Oliver - thanks for the tips! It looks like the `ã` is not returning a pair that links the first to the last element. I'm working on a way to get this to work, but thought I'd let you know. Thanks again though! https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEHMKUKHvEOHpEWHpEbOwkRpuWBxZSD2rOMg&input=LVE=

Comment: [43](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEHMKUKHvEOHpEWHpEbOwkRpuWBxZSD2rApjVWcp4yBtcWAgv3lzIGaOIA==&input=LVI=)?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think [this would work for 42](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEHMKUKHvEOHpEWHpEbOwkRpuWBxZSD2rArjMlXMIG1xYCC/eXMgZo4g&input=LVI=)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEHMKUKHvEOHpEWHpEbOwkRpuWBxZSD2rOoxIPIgbXFgIL95cyBmjiA=&input=LVI=)

Comment: Wait what does the `"q"` in the `.ö("q")` do

Comment: The letter "q" may be irrelevant. I think you throw any string into that function and it returns a "random permutation" of the array. I'm not totally sure, but that's the best I was able to determine.

Comment: Ah, it's `.ö(s)` where `s` is any string

Comment: You forgot to mention the mirror part (also, wonder how useful a titlecase builtin would be for string challenges like this)

Comment: Might be shorter using no delimiter (using `ò4` instead) but I'm too bad at Japt to modify Shaggy's compressor to work with no delimiter

Comment: [also 41 :/](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YEGYeUKHYkOHbERpuUWHbEafbmDyNCD2rOoxIPIgbXFgIL95cyBmjiA=&input=LVI=) ([metagolfer](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T2NbIkFuZHkiLCJCYXJiIiwiQ2FybCIsIkRpZGkiLCJFYXJsIiwiRnJhbiJd4SByQE9jWHEpbCA+T2NZcSlsID9ZOlh9IHE=&input=))

Comment: [lowercase is golfier](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T2NbImFuZHkiLCJiYXJiIiwiY2FybCIsImRpZGkiLCJlYXJsIiwiZnJhbiJd4SByQE9jWHEpbCA+T2NZcSlsID9ZOlh9IHE=&input=) but sadly no titlecase

Comment: @Shaggy - Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <strike>241</strike> 189 characters

```
import Data.List
import Random
main=randomRIO(0,719)>>=mapM_ putStrLn.f
f n=map(\(x,y)->x++" buys for "++y).zip(l n).tail$cycle$l n
l=(permutations(words"Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran")!!)
```

Fully random output (that still satisfies the spec).

This generates all permutations of the list of the names, picks one at random (I *think* this is the shortest way in Haskell to shuffle a list - if anyone has anything smaller, I'd appreciate it), and then each person then buys a present for the next person in the list.

Comment: I tried this ad-hoc, I'm not shure whether it works: http://paste.ubuntuusers.de/399798/

Comment: @Anon: `permutations$words"Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran"` and some other tricks I tried in my improved version. I forgot, that `permutations` isn't included in the 98 `List`, so you have to use the long name either. Have a look at it.

Comment: And for your special purpose: `r=tail.cycle`. and than inline it.

Comment: Got it down to **202** chars. Have a look: http://paste.ubuntuusers.de/399799/

Comment: And for **189** chars, replace the third line in my example with: `main=randomRIO(0,719)>>=mapM_ putStrLn.f`

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript: <s>72 64</s> 57 chars

```
"AndyBarbCarlDidiEarlFran"4/{;9rand}${.n+\' buys for '}%(
```

Tests

```
$ golfscript codegolf-838.gs 
Fran buys for Carl
Carl buys for Andy
Andy buys for Barb
Barb buys for Didi
Didi buys for Earl
Earl buys for Fran

$ golfscript codegolf-838.gs 
Didi buys for Earl
Earl buys for Andy
Andy buys for Barb
Barb buys for Carl
Carl buys for Fran
Fran buys for Didi
```

- Thanks gnibbler for `"AndyBarbCarlDidiEarlFran"4/`, updated and got 7 chars less
- 57 chars solution is basically by Nabb :D, and also noticed that `;9rand` is more random than my `6rand*`

Comment: `"AndyBarbCarlDidiEarlFran"4/`

Comment: ah ha, thank you @gnibbler, cool, going to update it.

Comment: Not sure why you're using `6rand*` -- `0=rand` or maybe `;9rand` is preferable. For the loop, `{.n+\' buys for '}%(` is shorter..

Comment: heh; became same chars count with J now :D and thank you @Nabb, I used `6rand*` because I thought It will equally randomize the 6 items array (I think I was wrong, since `;9rand` looks really random than mine)

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 83

```
$i=random 5
($n=-split'Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran')|%{"$_ buys for "+$n[++$i%6]}
```

History:

- 2011-02-11 22:01 **(136)** – First attempt.
- 2011-02-11 22:05 **(130)** – Inlined a few things. Shuffling the names now, not the indexes.
- 2011-02-13 16:13 **(128)** – I don't need the modulus as `$i` will be recreated every time.
- 2011-02-13 16:20   **(87)** – Borrowed the idea from [Anon.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45/anon)'s [C# solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/838/holiday-gift-exchange/840#840). Just generate a random offset and then just let them gift in circles.
- 2011-02-13 16:26   **(83)** – Changed random number generation and indexing. Pulled `$_` into the string to save the `+`.

Answer (score 3):

c99 -- 252 characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define G for(i=0;i<6;i++)
char*n="Andy\0Barb\0Carl\0Didi\0Earl\0Fran",*p[7];int i,j;int main()
{FILE*r=fopen("/dev/random","r");G p[i]=n+5*i;G{j=fgetc(r)%6;p[7]=p[j]
;p[j]=p[i];p[i]=p[7];}G printf("%s buys for %s\n",p[i],p[(i+1)%6]);}
```

Slight improvement by taking advantage of the circular nature of the permutation. This version *always* builds a loop-like buying strategy, so it is less random than the previous (271 character) version, but I believe it still meets the spec.

Requires a platform that has a working `/dev/random`. I ought to be able to knock about 8 off by omitting the `\0`s in the big string, but my libc doesn't seem to be dealing with `%4s` print specifiers the way the man page says.

The shuffle is bad, but doing it that way prevents me from having to check on *"Foo buys for Foo"* conditions.

**Readable:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *n="Andy\0Barb\0Carl\0Didi\0Earl\0Fran",
  *p[7]; /* 7th cell for temp */
int i,j;

int main(){
  FILE*r=fopen("/dev/random","r");
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    p[i]=n+5*i;   /* Initialize the pointers */
  for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    j=fgetc(r)%6; /* Poor numeric properties. Cest le Code Golf */
    p[7]=p[j];
    p[j]=p[i];
    p[i]=p[7];
  }
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%s buys for %s\n",p[i],p[(i+1)%6]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 118 chars

```
from random import*;L="Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran".split()
for i in sample(range(6),6):print L[i-1],"buys for",L[i]
```

**Python - 120 chars**

```
import random as R;L="Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran".split();R.shuffle(L)
for i in range(6):print L[i-1],"buys for",L[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

**R - 85 characters**

```
paste(n<-sample(c('Andy','Barb','Carl','Didi','Earl','Fran')),'buys for',n[c(6,1:5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 154 chars

```
import random as R;L="Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran".split();M=L[:]
while any(map(str.__eq__,L,M)):R.shuffle(M) 
for i in zip(L,M):print"%s buys for %s"%i
```

Comment: Apologies, my Python is severely lacking...is the while loop there basically looping until it finds a solution that avoids "X buys for X"?

Comment: @Steve: That's pretty much what it does. `map` calls `str.__eq__` on each pair of corresponding values in L and M, and the loop keeps going until none of them are true.

Comment: @Steve, yes. although it is probably shorter to jsut shift the records by a random amount from 1 to 5, I think that's not in the spirit of the question

Comment: When I first posed the question at work, you're exactly right. My coworkers quickly pointed out it wasn't ruled out by my definitions...so I left it as is when posting here.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <strike>210</strike> 183 characters

```
using System;class a{static void Main(){var n="Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran".Split();var c=0,i=new Random().Next(1,6);for(;c<6;c++)Console.WriteLine(n[c]+" buys for "+n[(c+i)%6]);}}
```

Heaps of boilerplate :(

This solution isn't totally random - there are always one or more "loops" of people e.g. A->C->E->A, and the offsets are always the same in the loops. However, it is not possible to predict the output of a particular run unless you have part of that output.

Comment: That's the interpretation I was intending (and basically the solution we landed on as well).

Comment: Should be 210. are you counting the newline at the end of the file?

Comment: @gnibbler: I probably was. I just catted the file into wc, I'm not really going to count that by hand.

Comment: What about `var n="Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran".Split()`? Saves 16 bytes. You can leave out the argument to `Main()`, which saves another 9 bytes. And you can combine the declaration of `c` and `i`: `int c,i=...;for(c=0;...` which saves another two.

Comment: @Joey: Tweaked it as per your suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## D: 233 Characters

```
import std.random,std.stdio;void main(){auto p=["Andy","Barb","Carl","Didi","Earl","Fran"];auto q=p.dup;o:while(1){for(int i;i<6;++i)if(p[i]==q[i]){randomShuffle(q);continue o;}break;}foreach(i,a;p)writefln("%s buys for %s",a,q[i]);}
```

More Legibly:

```
import std.random, std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto p = ["Andy", "Barb", "Carl", "Didi", "Earl", "Fran"];
    auto q = p.dup;

    o:while(1)
    {
        for(int i; i < 6; ++i)
            if(p[i] == q[i])
            {
                randomShuffle(q);
                continue o;
            }

        break;
    }

    foreach(i, a; p)
        writefln("%s buys for %s", a, q[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (175)

```
import random as r
n=['Andy','Barb','Carl','Didi','Earl','Fran']
m=n[:]
r.shuffle(m)
b=' buys for '
for i in n:
 h=m.pop()
 while h==i:
  m.append(h)
  h=m.pop()
 print(i+b+h)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme, 173

Gives one of two solutions.

```
(define(m lst)
    (printf"~v buys for ~v~n"(car lst)(cadr lst))
    (if(eq?(cadr lst)'Andy)0(m(cdr lst)))
)
(m((if(odd?(random 2))reverse values)'(Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran Andy)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 89 chars

```
(a=%w(Andy Barb Carl Didi Earl Fran).shuffle).zip(a.reverse).each{|e|puts e*' buys for '}
```

Output:

```
Andy buys for Didi
Barb buys for Earl
Fran buys for Carl
Carl buys for Fran
Earl buys for Barb
Didi buys for Andy
```

Comment: You can use `map` instead of `each`.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that if you have an odd number of people the middle person will gift themselves

Earl buys for Mark
Fran buys for Andy
Barb buys for Carl
Didi buys for Didi
Carl buys for Barb
Andy buys for Fran
Mark buys for Earl

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 41 bytes

```
"δ%è╘+µ√♂JÇ"2/$╦╕ää▐δáw_╪" buys for "+m+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9tYXRoZ29sZv//Is60JcOo4pWYK8K14oia4pmCSsOHIjIvJOKVpuKVlcOkw6TilpDOtMOhd1/ilaoiIGJ1eXMgZm9yICIrbStu//8)

### Explanation

This is not guaranteed to produce each case with equal probability, but it does produce different results each run. One byte could be removed if I had a shuffle operator, but that's for another day.

```
"δ%è╘+µ√♂JÇ"                                push the string "δ%è╘+µ√♂JÇ"
            2/                              split into segments of two characters
              $                             transform to ordinals using base 256
               ╦                            fetch dictionary words (['Andy', 'barb', 'Carl', 'Earl', 'Fran'])
                ╕ää                         Push "didi"
                   ▐                        append to end of list
                    δ                       capitalize all strings in list
                     áw                     sort by random character in each string (shuffle)
                       _                    duplicate TOS
                        ╪                   right-rotate bits in int, list, str
                         " buys for "       push the string " buys for "
                                     +      Add to all strings in list
                                      m+    zip add the two arrays
                                        n   join array with newline
```