# Christmas Lists

Tags: code-golf

The challenge is to create one program that will accept as arguments (arrays of arrays) or on standard input (line-by-line, separated by commas) a collection of families and names, like so:

```
John,Anna
Mark,James
Elizabeth,Daniel,Isabelle
Ryan,Ruth
```

As well as two other arguments (two more arrays of pairs, as arrays) or on standard input (a blank line after the preceding input, followed by two comma-separated lists on two lines with an `=` separating pairings; see example) that represent the two previous years' Christmas lists:

```
John=Mark,James=Anna,Elizabeth=Ryan,...
John=Isabelle,Ryan=Elizabeth,Daniel=Mark,...
```

The function/program must return/output (in any format) a way that each person is assigned somebody to give a present to, following these rules:

1. A person cannot give a present to him or herself.
2. A person cannot give a present to anybody in his or her own family.
3. A person cannot be assigned the same person he or she was assigned in any of the two previous years.

If such a matching is impossible for every person, output/return `null` or nothing or something appropriate.

This is a code golf, so shortest code wins, but I'll also give a bounty to the code that runs fastest (on my computer, at least, though results shouldn't vary much).

Comment: Are the gift assignments symmetric?  The text doesn't say so, but using `=` to represent the assignments suggests it...

Comment: Shouldn't the number of people be guaranteed to be even?

Comment: @KeithRandall: No, they aren't symmetric.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: No, because they aren't symmetric. (`Dan=Marge,Marge=Carolyn,Carolyn=Don,Don=Bob,Bob=Dan`)

Comment: -1: Bad timing, imho. Summertime, and the living is easy. Instead we shall work out xmas stuff?

Comment: @userunknown What, we can't prepare early for christmas? I like to buy my christmas cards in January in the sales. :-) Seriously though, I think -1 for being unseasonal is a little harsh.

Comment: @userunknown: Summer is the best time to shop for winter holidays because you're often going shoppable places, and nobody else is thinking to do it :) [Also, -1? Okay, then...]

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate as this version has additional restrictions): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/838/holiday-gift-exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 90 characters

```
+:q;:f[]*:^[]:r\{.,{(^3${1=}%-f{2$\?)},~-q{(3$={-.}*;}/{.[[2$\]]4$|3$c;}%;;;}{;:r}if;}:c~r
```

The program does a simple recursive search on the names. It actually calculates all possible lists but saves them to a variable for output, so only the last one is returned.

The input/output is on the interpreter stack (first families then two previous years` assignments), e.g.

```
#PREPARE INPUT
;
[["John" "Anna"]["Mark" "James"]["Elizabeth" "Daniel" "Isabelle"]["Ryan" "Ruth"]]
[["Ruth" "John"] ["Ryan" "Daniel"] ["Isabelle" "Mark"] ["Daniel" "Anna"] ["Elizabeth" "James"] ["James" "Elizabeth"] ["Mark" "Ryan"] ["Anna" "Isabelle"] ["John" "Ruth"]]
[["Ruth" "Anna"] ["Ryan" "Elizabeth"] ["Isabelle" "John"] ["Daniel" "James"] ["Elizabeth" "Mark"] ["James" "Daniel"] ["Mark" "Isabelle"] ["Anna" "Ruth"] ["John" "Ryan"]]

#PROGRAM
+:q;:f[]*:^[]:r\{.,{(^3${1=}%-f {2$\?)},~-q{(3$={-.}*;}/{.[[2$\]]4$|3$c;}%;;;}{;:r}if;}:c~r

#SHOW OUTPUT
p
```

prints the output

```
[["Ruth" "Elizabeth"] ["Ryan" "John"] ["Isabelle" "James"] ["Daniel" "Mark"] ["Elizabeth" "Anna"] ["James" "Ruth"] ["Mark" "Daniel"] ["Anna" "Ryan"] ["John" "Isabelle"]]
```