# Secret Santa Challenge

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, fastest-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Holiday Gift Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/838/holiday-gift-exchange)

**Background:**
Secret Santa is a Western Christmas tradition in which members of a group or community are randomly assigned a person to whom they anonymously give a gift.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa

> 

Ok, me and my work colleges did this today during our lunch hour - we made a secret algorithm santa pick random gifters and receivers.

Think of this question as a Christmas Programming Challenge to see who can come up with some of the most elegant solutions for this problem.

**Input:**
The input should be an array ['Oliver', 'Paul', 'Rowan', 'Darren', 'Nick', 'Atif', 'Kevin']

**Output**
A representation of something similar to key value pairs for the gifter and receiver. e.g.

```
Oliver -> Darren,
Paul -> Nick,
Rowan -> Kevin
Kevin -> Atif,
Darren -> Paul,
Nick -> Oliver,
Atif -> Rowan
```

**Deadline:** 15th December (for those late christmas shoppers)

**Remember:** you cannot have a person choosing themselves and the program must not spiral off into an infinite loop when gifter == receiver when there is only one person left.

**Rules:**

1. Must not have duplicates
2. Must be random (we all have different views on what is random - but you get my gist)
3. No Language constraints
4. Have fun

Here is mine (not golfed) in ruby:

```
require 'pp'

def move(array, from, to)
  array.insert(to, array.delete_at(from))
end

gifters = ['Oliver', 'Paul', 'Rowan', 'Darren', 'Nick', 'Atif', 'Kevin'].shuffle!
recievers = gifters.dup

move recievers, recievers.count - 1, 0

pp Hash[gifters.zip recievers]
```

which spits out:

```
{"Nick"=>"Darren",
 "Paul"=>"Nick",
 "Kevin"=>"Paul",
 "Rowan"=>"Kevin",
 "Atif"=>"Rowan",
 "Oliver"=>"Atif",
 "Darren"=>"Oliver"}
```

Comment: Input? Or do you want it hard-coded, as in your example? Does the resulting derangement have to be a single cycle, as implemented by your code, or can it be a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: I should have made it clearer in my post. The input should be an array ['Oliver', 'Paul', 'Rowan', 'Darren', 'Nick', 'Atif', 'Kevin'] and it can be a product of disjoint cycles - the rules are pretty open.

Comment: this is kinda trivial for a code challenge tag, and only one answer appears to be golf'd, so uh what's the objective here?

Comment: It's not quite *exactly* the same, the other one has a hardcoded list.

Comment: the challenge is for fun - to produce the code in different languages with different approaches. The approach with the best intuitive wins (probably based on up votes, so the mass can decide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## k (<s>29</s> 20 chars)

```
{i!(1_i),*i:(-#x)?x}
```

<s>{i!@[i:(-:#x)?x;,/|2 0N#!#x]}</s>

Example

```
k){i!(1_i),*i:(-#x)?x}`person1`person2`person3`person4`person5
person2| person1
person5| person3
person4| person2
person1| person5
person3| person4
```

Explanation - as above, shuffles list and maps to rotation of itself.

Comment: very small - where can i get a copy of k to run this?

Comment: You can grab an evaluation version of the interpreter here http://kx.com/software.php . It's one interpreter for both q and k

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby - <strike>161</strike> 42 chars

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'

gifters = CSV.read(ARGV[0]).first

receivers = gifters.shuffle!.dup
puts Hash[gifters.zip(receivers << receivers.shift)]
```

Usage

```
./secret_santa path_to_some_csv
=> {"Edward"=>"Alan", "Alan"=>"Charlie", "Charlie"=>"Dave", "Dave"=>"Brett", "Brett"=>"Edward"}
```

### Update

```
r=ARGV.shuffle!.dup;p ARGV.zip(r<<r.shift)
```

Comment: As this is a code golf problem, I added the language and char count to your answer. I think there's still potential to shorten the code, for example using single char variable names or removing line breaks.

Comment: This can be shortened to 38 by replacing ARGV by $* `r=$*.shuffle!.dup;p $*.zip(r<<r.shift)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSMutableArray *people =
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"Oliver", @"Paul", @"Rowan", @"Darren", @"Nick", @"Atif", @"Kevin"]];
    [people sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
         return (arc4random_uniform(3)-1);
    }];

    for (int i = 0;  i < [people count]; i++)
        NSLog(@"%@ gifts %@", people[i], people[(i+1)%[people count]]);
```